# Swift, How to sync reverseGeocodeLocation function (by using semaphore or dispatch group....etc)

Tags: swift, synchronization, completionhandler, reversegeocodelocation

In viewDidLoad, I call reverseGeocodeLocation to get geo info. but It is async API and I need a sync flow. However, I could not sync this flow. because when I inject semaphore in the flow, reverseGeocodeLocation's completion handler is not working in forced sync flow case. (I used semaphore for sync). It just stopped and `completionHandler` is not invoked. What should I do? Thanks to read. The code below is my sample.

```
let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
  
  let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
  
  CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
    print("completion")
    var placeMark: CLPlacemark! = placemarks?.first
    
    semaphore.signal()
  })
  semaphore.wait()
```

---

Comment it myself.
It's impossible to use reverseGeocodeLocation synchronous.

The link below (Apple public) it explain.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation

Geocoding requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many requests in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail. When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder passes an error object with the value CLError.Code.network to your completion handler.

Comment: what you exactly want to achieve ?

Comment: its not a good idea to use `DispatchSemaphore` or `dispatchGroup` for one `reverseGeocodeLocation` async call ... just update on results ...

Comment: I want to get a local photo(having location degree) list when view did load case initailly load. It's not a normal pattern? I'm a newbie ios developing.